# Bad request при срабатывании JQUERY-скрипта

Tags: jquery

С веб-страницы пытаюсь взаимодействовать с WCF-службой, хостом для которой является Windows-служба. Получаю "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request". Скрипт приведён ниже. Просьба помочь.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars",
            datatype: "xml",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
            data: "<id>1</id>",
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Error:"+err.toString());
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#content").html(data);                   
            }
        });
    });
```

Пытаюсь отправить так:

```
var t = 'POST /url HTTP/1.1\
    Host: http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service\
    Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\
    Content-length: 350\
    SoapAction: http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars\
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
    <soap:Body>\
      <GetCars xmlns="http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars">\
        <id>123</id>\
      </GetCars>\
    </soap:Body>\
  </soap:Envelope>';

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars",
            datatype: "xml",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
            data: t,
            processData: false,
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Error:"+err.toString());
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#content").html(data);                   
            }
        });
    });
```

Получаю Bad request. Просьба помочь.

Comment: Есть возможность посмотреть логи конечной службы / полный текст ответа?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2015 13:12:07 GMT

Comment: то есть ответ вообще никакого сообщения об ошибке не содержит? и вы уверены, что `<id>1</id>` не нужно оборачивать в дополнительную обертку?

Comment: Текст ответа является пустым.

Comment: Наверное, обёртка нужна, так как WCF работает через SOAP.

Comment: Попробуйте [эту штуку](https://plugins.jquery.com/soap/), должна взять на себя основную рутину.

Comment: JQuery.soap попробовал. Довёл до результата, когда ошибка пояляется на сервере ("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"). Без JQuery.soap получаю Bad request. Отправляю данные с обёрткой - не помогает.

Comment: При использовании JQuery.soap получаю ошибку "Сообщение содержит неверный или просроченный токен контекста безопасности. Сообщение не было обработано".

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars",
            type: "POST",
            data: "<id>1</id>"
            success: function (data) {
                $("#content").html(data);                   
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Получилось: "HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'."

Comment: @AN90, ммм, покажите все код. Если не жалко :)

Comment: Не жалко, но Bad request означает синтаксическую ошибку запроса - в данном случае выполняемого через JQUERY - не так ли? Я предполагаю, что ошибка в скрипте.

Comment: 400 говорит о том, что сервис неправильно запрашивается, я предполагаю, что он не может прочитать параметры запроса.

Comment: Нужен код службы или веб-страницы?

Comment: @AN90, не знаю...

Comment: Один из вариантов отправки данных с обёрткой я добавил выше в вопросе. Данные пытаюсь отправить WCF-службе, хостом для которой является Windows-служба.